# Setting Stormpath Configuration Options

Tags: configuration, stormpath

I am trying to customize the registration page with Stormpath and I can't figure out why the configuration options are not working.  The enableXXX and requireXXX work, but none of the info inside web:{...} is showing up. I've tried reordering the options, but that doesn't work either.

Specifically, I want to:

-- Register users at /signup instead of /register. Right now only /register is working.

-- I want to redirect them to another site after registration.  I randomly put google.com in there, but I'm still redirected to "/" after registration is complete.

-- I want to reorder the registration fields. I want email to be the first field, but username is currently first.

Here's app.js:

```
// Import required modules.
var express = require('express');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');
var path = require('path');
var engine = require('ejs-mate');
var app = express();

// use ejs-locals for all ejs templates: 
  app.engine('ejs', engine);

// Configure public views
  app.set('views','./views');

app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  apiKeyFile: process.env[(process.platform == 'win32') ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'] + ~removed
  secretKey: '~removed',
  application: '~removed',
  enableRegistration: true,
  enableGivenName: false,
  requireGivenName: false,
  enableSurname: false,
  requireSurname: false,
  website: true,
  api: true,
  web: {
    register: {
      uri: '/signup',  // Use a different URL
      nextUri: 'http://google.com',    // Where to send the user to, if auto login is enabled
      fields: {
        passwordConfirm: {
          enabled: true,
          required: true
        }
      },
      fieldOrder: [ "email", "username", "password", "passwordConfirm" ],

    }
  },
  enableUsername: true,
  requireUsername: true,
  enableConfirmPassword: true,
  requireConfirmPassword: true

}
));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home.ejs', {
    title: 'Welcome'
  });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('home page!');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Other possibly relevant info:

-- The site is hosted on Heroku, but I'm not using the Stormpath add-on because I couldn't get it to work.

-- I'm on a Mac.

I've been stuck on this for days and I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of Stormpath did you use?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely this: we released a new version of this library recently which has new configuration options, and it appears you are using our OLD docs as a reference.

Here's what you'll want to do:

Update to the latest express-stormpath release. Then use the code below: (I converted your example to work with the latest release):

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  client: {
    apiKey: {
      file: process.env[(process.platform == 'win32') ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'] + '~removed'
    }
  },
  application: {
    href: '~removed',
  },
  web: {
    register: {
      enabled: true,
      uri: '/signup',
      nextUri: 'http://google.com',  // don't send them here =)
      fields: {
        username: {
          enabled: true,
          required: true
        },
        givenName: {
          enabled: false,
          required: false
        },
        surname: {
          enabled: false,
          required: false
        },
        passwordConfirm: {
          enabled: true,
          required: true
        }
      },
      fieldOrder: ['username', 'email', 'password', 'passwordConfirm']
    }
  },
  website: true,
  api: true
}));
```